# customtkinter - align text in CTkLabel

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I want my text to be aligned to the left (or west).

My code:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")

label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=root,
 text="this is a label",
 text_color="#fff",
 bg_color="green",
 width=250,
 justify="left",
 anchor="w"
)

label.place(x=0, y=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Even with `justify="left"` and `anchor="w"` nothing changes and the text is centered. Why? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Actually `CTKLabel` is a `Frame` and the text is a `Label` inside that frame.  The text is put at center of the frame using `place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')`. So the `justify` and `anchor` options passed to `CTKLabel` does not work.

However, you can move the text after creating the instance as below:

```py
label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=root,
 text="this is a label",
 text_color="#fff",
 bg_color="green",
 width=250,
 justify="left",
 anchor="w"
)
label.text_label.place(relx=0, anchor='w') # move the text to the left side of frame
label.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Or making the text to fill the frame horizontally:

```py
label.text_label.place(relwidth=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding justify worked for me. I was able to center align the text inside the Custom TKinter textbox (CTKEntry)

example:

```
testEntry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=f1,
                               justify=CENTER,
                               width=120,
                               height=120,
                               corner_radius=2)
```

Regards,
V.M.Guruprasath

Answer (score 0):

This could be solve your problem: anchor=ctk.W

And here is the code:

```
label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=root,
  text="this is a label",
  text_color="#fff",
  bg_color="green",
  anchor=ctk.W)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).